# sass folding syntax

Tags: folding, syntax

i have `foldmethod=indent` on a `.sass` file.  it auto-folds most blocks fine, except for `#id` selectors, which it folds into the block above it.  for example:

```
:root  // folds 3 lines below
    --base-bg: #131a21
    --text: #ddb
    --link-text: #4ad

body  // folds 3 lines below
    background: var(--base-bg)
    margin: 0
    height: 100%

*  // folds 2 lines below
    color: var(--text)
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif

.overlay // folds until .chat
    position: absolute
    background: #000a
    width: 100%
    height: 100%

#chatLog // folds into .overlay
    max-width: 30em
    height: 20em

#chatInput // folds into .overlay
    max-width: 26em

.chat // folds 2 lines
    background: #2e1e2e
    font-family: monospace
```

do i need to change vim's `.sass` syntax rules?

Answer (score 2):

The lines starting with `#` are being ignored for indent-based folding due to the [`'foldignore'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27foldignore%27) setting, which defaults to `#`.

That is usually meant to ignore lines with comments (in many scripting languages) or with `#ifdef` type of directives (on the C pre-processor.)

You can easily fix that by clearing that option:

```
setlocal foldignore=
```